# p-group as a product of two abelian normal subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Thanks for any comment or answer.

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian $p$-group such that $G=AB$  where $A=C_G(a)$  and $B=C_G(b)$ are maximal abelian normal subgroups of $G$ such that $A\cap B=Z(G)$, and for every element 
$a_1\in A\setminus Z(G)$ (respectively $b_1\in B\setminus Z(G)$) ,
we have $C_G(a_1)=A$ (respectively $C_G(b_1)=B$). Is it true that centralizer of every noncentral element of $G$ is abelian?

Comment: The answer is no. I found a counterexample on a computer of order $3^{11}$ with $|A|=|B|=3^8$ and $Z(G) = 3^5$. I would not be surprised if there are smaller examples.But with questions like this, I feel that you should give some indication of why you think such a result might be true. Although you have made enough assumptions to make it moderately hard to find a countexample, my immediate reaction was that this is almost certainly not true.

Comment: @DerekHolt Please consider adding your Magma(?) construction of the group as an answer (and, if you want, explain your thought process a little bit). I'm sure the op would appreciate seeing this as well.

Comment: As a matter of fact, given that A and B are maximal Abelian normal subgroups with $G = AB,$ it is necessarily the case that $Z(G) = A \cap B,$ so some of your hypotheses are redundant. For the maximality of $A$ and $B$ certainly forces $Z(G) \leq A \cap B.$ On the other hand, if $x \in A \cap B,$ then $C_{G}(x) \geq \langle A,B \rangle = G,$ and hence $A \cap B \leq Z(G).$ I agree with Derek that (in this and some of your other questions) it would be better if you gave more information about how and why you arrived at the hypotheses used, and why an answer to the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Yes I used Magma. It is hard to explain how I came up with this example. I started by trying with 2-generator subgroups A/Z(P) and B/Z(P) but I
couldn't make that work, so I moved to three generators.

```
/* First construct a group containing two 3-generator abelian subgroups
 * <a,b,c> and <d,e,f> and add a few somewhat randomly chosen relations
 * among their commutators.
 * Note that the commutator a^-1 b^-1 a b is denoted (a,b) in Magma
 */
> X := Group< a,b,c,d,e,f | (a,b), (a,c), (b,c), (d,e), (e,f), (d,f),
>                    (a,d)=(b,e), (a,e)=(b,f), (a,f)=(c,d), (b,d)=(c,e) >;
/* Form the class two exponent 3 3-quotient P of X, which will be our
 * counterexample
 */
> P := pQuotient(X, 3, 2 : Exponent:=3 );
> FactoredOrder(P);
[ <3, 11> ]
> Z := Centre(P);
> FactoredOrder(Z);
[ <3, 5> ]
/* Define the abelian subgroups A and B of P and check all of the
 * required conditions
 */
> A := sub< P | P.1, P.2, P.3, Z >;
> B := sub< P | P.4, P.5, P.6, Z >;
> FactoredOrder(A), FactoredOrder(B);
[ <3, 8> ] [ <3, 8> ]
> IsElementaryAbelian(A), IsElementaryAbelian(B);
true true
> A meet B eq Z;
true
> sub< P | A, B > eq P;
true
> forall{ a: a in A | a in Z or Centraliser(P,a) eq A };
true
> forall{ b: b in B | b in Z or Centraliser(P,b) eq B };
true
> forall(g){ g : g in P | g in Z or IsAbelian(Centraliser(P,g)) };
false
> g;
P.2 * P.5
```